# BigQuery Testing, Debugging, and Design Patterns

Tags: google-bigquery

We use BigQuery as the main data warehouse in our company.

We have gotten very efficient with SQL syntax and we write multi-page SQL queries with valid Syntax to analyze our data.

The main problem that we are struggling with are terrible logic mistakes in our queries. For example, it could be that a > should have been a >=, or that a join was treating NULL values the wrong way.

The effect is that we are getting wrong data out of BigQuery.

The logic within our data structure is so complicated ("what again was the definition of Customer Type ABC?") that it's terribly difficult to actually pull out anything useable. We estimate that up to 50% of analytics that we pull out of BigQuery are plain wrong.

Of course this is a problem that significantly hurts our bottom line and leads to wrong business decision. It has gotten so bad that we are craving for a normalized database structure that at least could be comprehended easier.

My hope is that maybe we are just missing certain design patterns to properly use BigQuery. However I find *zero* guidance about this online. The SQL we are using is so complex that I'm starting to think that although the Syntax is correct, SQL was not made for this. What we are doing feels like fitting a complex program into a single function, which in turn becomes untestable and a nightmare to work with.

I would appreciate any input and guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can empathize here. I don't think your issue is unique, and there isn't one best practice. I can tell you what we have done to help with these same issues.

We are a small team of analysts, and only have a couple TB of data to crunch daily so your mileage will vary with these tips depending on your situation.

We use DBT - https://www.getdbt.com/. It has a free command line version, or you can pay for DBT cloud if you aren't confident with command line tools. It will help you go from Pages long SQL queries to smaller digestible chunks that are easier to maintain.

It helps with 3 main use cases for us.

1. database normalization/summarization - you can easily write queries, have them dependent on each other, have them scheduled to run at a certain time, while doing a lot of the more complex data engineering tasks for you. Such as making sure to run things in the right order, and that no circular references exist. This part of the tool helped us migrate away from pages long SQL queries to smaller digestible chunks that are useful in multiple applications.
2. documentation: there is a documentation site built in. So you can document a column and write out the definition of 'customer' easily.
3. Testing. We write loads of tests. We have a 100% accepted answer to certain metrics. Any time we need to reference this metric in other queries, or transform data to slice that metric by other dimensions, we write a test to make sure the new transformation matches back to the 100% accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have explored DBT, unfortunately we didn't have the bandwidth to support it at the company level. As an alternative we use airflow to build and maintain datasets in Bigquery. We use the [BigQuery operators](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html) to interface with BQ through airflow. This helps us in the following ways:

1. Ability to build custom operators that can help with organizational level bells and whistles (integration with internal systems, data lifecycle management, lineage management etc.)
2. Ability to break down complex pieces of SQL into smaller manageable blocks that can be reused
3. Ability to incorporate testing in the process. You can build testing into your pipeline DAG or can build out separate DAGs of tests that can monitor your datasets and send out reports.
4. Ability to replay and recreate datasets
5. Ability to easily manage schema changes

I am sure there are other use cases where airflow helps, but these are some of the things that come to mind.

Comment: We also use Airflow along with DBT. For strictly sql based work/scheduling, DBT is 100x easier to maintain than airflow.

 If you need to automate a bunch of tasks, like pulling api data, or scheduling emails etc. then I do recommend airflow. But if you are transforming raw data in a database, then it is much easier in dbt. 

in fact, our daily airflow jobs have tasks where we run dbt jobs.